# Git push cause remote to have untracked files

Tags: ubuntu, git

Recently, both our Git remotes (one a production server, and the other a staging one) cause issues when pushing changes.

Typically :

#### Local

```
git add <list of untracked files>
git commit -m <message>
git push <remote> <remote active branch>
```

#### Remote

```
git status
On branch <active branch>
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

.... all the files that have been committed ....
```

We are not sure what could've changed in the recent weeks because everything worked fine before.

We currently fix this by connecting to the remove server and executing

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Why is this happening and how can we fix this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! Does your remote application write logs on its working directory? Looks like on the remote server there are (new?) files which aren't on your local repository.

Comment: Hi, how can there be remote files that aren't in my local when I push the changes **from** the local repository? I have tried adding the `git reset --hard HEAD` in the `post-receive` hook, but it does nothing; the script looks like it's never get called.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your setup correctly, you are pushing to a non-bare repository. What happens is that the working directory is not automatically updated when you do this. You are correct that the `git reset --hard` command fixes this. The reason your hook does not run is that the working directory and/or work tree may not be correctly set in the middle of a pull. To fix this, you can explicitly set it. There is an environment variable, `GIT_DIR`, that git sets for hooks. It corresponds to your `.git` folder. Using this, we can set your git tree correctly.

Here is the script I have used for this exact scenario before:

```
#!/bin/bash

git --work-tree "$GIT_DIR/.." reset --hard
```

As you can see, since your `.git` is always a subdirectory of the root directory of the repo, this just ensures the work tree is the right place to reset it.